# Bigquery SQL - Count of array values that appear twice

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I have an array of ID values and I wish to count the number of values that appear exactly twice in each array. Below is an example of the data and desired outcome:

[image]

I have the following code that can count the total (or could count the distinct total) of values but I can't figure out how I need to modify it so that it only counts the ID's that appear twice.

```
SELECT mth_end_date, 
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(user)) AS id) segment_count
FROM temp2
```

I know I am missing something really obvious here, but I just can't crack it.

Appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

[image]

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mikhail - you are a legend! And apologies for not providing the dataset in the question!

Comment: lol. i am glad you got the point :o)